# Why camera not work in Android 5?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-5.0-lollipop

In android 2.3, 4, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4 works correctly

I've this function with android 2.3 api:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
   // 1º Si se esta viendo preview, se detiene
   if (mPreviewRunning) {
      mCamera.stopPreview();
   }
   // 2º Se setean los nuevos parametros de la camara
   Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
   p.setPreviewSize(w, h);
   mCamera.setParameters(p);

   // 3º Volvemos a mostrar el preview
   try {
      mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(ctxt, "Error refreshing camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
   }

   mCamera.startPreview();
   mPreviewRunning = true;
}
```

The app crash in line, return

error: W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

```
mCamera.setParameters(p);
```

after return this:

W/System.err: java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

This is my manifest for my two apps:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.foca.deboSancion"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="14.7" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.foca.deboComun"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `mCamera.setParameters(p);` is not lollypop(android 5.0) api issue, its device specific. Most of the devices behaviour with the camera parameters are is final, I mean ur cannot change it, if you try it will crash. Easy possible solution use of try catch, advanced is use reflection (suggestion : dont go for this)